# CORS Angular 2 interceptor

Tags: http, cors, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

When i ask to **"api/authenticate"** or **"api/account"**, interceptor sends me to http://localhost:8443 (http://localhost:8443/api/authenticate for example), but in other cases (**"api/plan-reports"** for example) i need to ask to http://localhost:8443/hermessm/api/plan-reports.
 So i have the error below.

Does anyone know how to fix it?
It seems to me the error from interceptor. Please, help me!

### interceptor.ts

```
request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return this.intercept(super.request(url, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options)));
}

get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    url = this.updateUrl(url);
    return super.get(url, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options));
}

post(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    url = this.updateUrl(url);
    return super.post(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options));
}

put(url: string, body: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    url = this.updateUrl(url);
    return super.put(url, body, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options));
}

delete(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    url = this.updateUrl(url);
    return super.delete(url, this.getRequestOptionArgs(options));
}

getRequestOptionArgs(options?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs {
    if (!options) {
        options = new RequestOptions();
    }
    if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = new Headers();
    }
    options.withCredentials = true;
    return !this.firstInterceptor ? options : this.firstInterceptor.processRequestInterception(options);
}


intercept(observable: Observable<Response>): Observable<Response> {
    return !this.firstInterceptor ? observable : this.firstInterceptor.processResponseInterception(observable);
}

private updateUrl(req: string) {
    if (req.indexOf("api/authenticate") !== -1 || req.indexOf("api/account") !== -1) {
        console.log(environment.gataway + '/' + req)
        return environment.gataway + '/' + req;
    }
    else if (req.indexOf("api/") !== -1) {
            return environment.gataway + '/hermessm/' + req;
    }
    else {
        return req;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You already seem to have some CORS support on the server. You need to read and understand the error messages the browser’s logging. The browser is saying that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin the server is sending has multiple values: it apparently has `http://localhost:4200` the value twice. It should only have that once. So regardless of whatever other problems you might need to fix, you need to fix that one or else nothing else is going to work anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was my interceptor. I don't resolve this problem, but i removed the interceptor and added proxy-server to my project

Comment: Also interceptor is suitable only once (not twice)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using web API

These days browsers don't allow to access services from other domain that's why you are getting this error.

You need to install CORS, so run following command on you package manager console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

Add following lines to your webapiconfig.cs file

```
  var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:xxx", "*", "*");
  config.EnableCors(cors);
```

Now you are ready to go

Comment: Where I need to install CORS?

Comment: Do you mean enable cors in server that contain frontend app? Is it help to browser?

Comment: Your service should be enabled, "http://localhost:8443" I think this is your Web API, so you need to enable in your Wen API

Comment: We don't use web API, just dynamic  replace part of url. But okey, we try to enable cors, but where is it must enable, on js side or another backend side?

Comment: It must be on the server side (backend)